# VIM execute command after write ":w"

Tags: linux, vim

Is it possible to always automatically call a command (for example `:set invnu`) right after I execute `:w`? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: `:help autocommand`.

Comment: Thanks :-) exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:au BufWritePost * :set invnu`
Better add file extension filter to replace the * above.